# A variable isnt working in my Java application

Tags: java

I try to compile this string:

```
public class Dimensions
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        boolean[][] points = new boolean[5][20] ;
        points[0][5] = true ;
        points[1][6] = true ;
        points[2][7] = true ;
        points[3][8] = true ;
        points[4][9] = true ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < points.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "\n" ) ;
        }
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < points.length ; j++)
        {
            char mark = ( points[i][j] ) ? 'X' : '-' ;
            System.out.println( mark ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

But javac gives me the error

> Dimensions.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>                           char mark = ( points[i][j] ) ? 'X' : '-' ;
>                                                ^   symbol:   variable i   location: class Dimensions 1 error

Its like `i` doesnt even exist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Correct; it doesn't exist in *that loop*

Comment: Variables declared inside a for-statement's initialization expression, only exist inside the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `i` became out of scope once its `for` loop ended.

Perhaps you meant to nest the `j` for loop inside the `i` for loop.  Then `i` would still be in scope for the entire `j` for loop.